# 8-bit binary U/D counter with rotary encoder

Tags: integrated-circuit, counter, encoder

Im trying to make 8-bit binary counter using CD4516 / HEF4516 (doesnt matter, both act same).

My circuit works well excepct one error. 
I can successfully go from `00000000` to `11111111` and over again, i can do the same in backwards direction.

Error only occurs when i have `1000` on lower counter go to `0000` and back to `1000`, then the second IO acts weird.

Error is not in arduino, nor the PISO, id does the same with directly connecteed LEDs.

Anyone have an ide? Thanks.

[image: Photo of circuit]
[image: Scheme]
[image: States]

---

EDIT: working circuit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your layout.

1) In general, you MUST provide decoupling caps at each IC, particularly when using a breadboard. This should be a 0.1 uF ceramic cap, run directly from Vcc to Gnd on each chip, with the cap leads as short as possible, and the connection to the IC made as close to the pin as possible. In other words, don't put the cap somewhere else and run jumpers. 1 cap per IC.

2) Just as important, ALL unused inputs must be tied to ground or Vcc. On ALL chips. Letting them float, particularly with CMOS, is to invite all sorts or bizarre, intermittent, unreproducible problems. The very high imput impedance of CMOS allows your inputs to act as antennas and pick up signals occurring elsewhere on the board. And when I say ALL unused inputs, I include, for instance, the input pins on the unused half of your flip-flop, even though that "obviously" doesn't count. Trust me on this.

3) Get rid of that cap between clock and data - it is coupling the edges from one to the other.

4) Run your signals from the Arduino to the breadboard via twisted pairs, with the other wire in each pair connected to ground.

5) Do not use the same clock for the flip-flop and the counters unless you know exactly what you're doing. You risk what is called "metastability". In this case, you probably won't get burned, but it's a bad idea in general. If you must do it, run a third line to the counter enable, and disable the counter when you update the flip-flop. Of course, if you do that, there's no need for the flip-flop in the first place, but you'll need to be careful not to take short cuts and change the U/D control at the same time you issue a clock command.

6) With the above changes, try the "proper" counter configuration again. Run the first carry output (pin 7) to the second counter's carry in (pin 5), and connect both clocks together.

Comment: Thank, ill give a try, just a two questions. 
3) Without the capacitor on rotary encoder, there are sometimes bounce-backs, so  it probably has to be there.
5) The clock is from the rotary encoder, i see no other way, im using this idea: http://www.vlsiencyclopedia.com/2011/07/application-of-synchronous-updown.html, ill try the rest.

Ill try to do everything you told me now.

Comment: @Aiphee - Your vlsi link is just wrong. Get rid of the flip flop and run the two inputs directly. Put a 100 pF cap on each line, connected to ground, not each other. If you can provide a link to the encoder data sheet, I may be able to help more.

Comment: Its a classical, gray code encoder, i need to decode it , to get up/dwn line and clock. There will be many modules like this, so i cant send gray code to arduino for decoding.
http://www.tme.eu/cz/details/ed16111o/enkodery/ctr/ed16111o-fb20b12-a24-100-g12/

Comment: @Aiphee - A 2-bit grey code is nothing more than a standard quadrature signal. You do not need the flip-flop. You use one signal for clock and the other for direction. The only difference in the two is which direction count you produce. And your link does not provide a usable interface guide.

Comment: I cant believe it, after so many hours its working! I didnt thought it would work without a D flip-flop, since signals should be 90 deg phased.  But it does work. It works even without the capacitor and all legs connected, but i will take the advice and make all noted thinks for PCB production. Thank you :) PS: edited original post with photo of working circuit.

Comment: @Aiphee - If you're making a pcb, allow for a series resistor/cap to ground for each encoder input - your final environment may have noise that needs to be filtered out. And a link to a working data sheet for the encoder would be very useful. Finally, if you're making a pcb, make very sure that your ground is solid. You need wide traces connecting the IC grounds. Trying to do something with a 2-layer board may be a learning experience for you. Be prepared for problems.

Comment: Do you mean a low-pass filter? I couldnt find the datasheet for the encoder, but it works if connected like in the picture, my plus is, that the direction order doesn't matter, since i will map values in Arduino. PCB will truly be an experience, since i only did one sided PCB with acid and alcohol marker so far. I will do that in KiCad and then probably ask someone at near university for opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two recommended ways of cascading the 4510 on the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4510b.pdf) and you are using something else:

[image]

Note the use of a 2-input OR gate for when you use ripple clocking.

Comment: I tried it, but no change, if something, it acts even weirder. I`ll double-check it.

Comment: OK, similar result: http://imgur.com/a/u9Ql5 (first end second). Please, look if im using pull up rezistor on clock right, it doesnt work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic does not connect the carry signal as recommended by the datasheet. So with speculation I think the C.O. signal is not behaving as you think it does, making a glitch.

A little reading shows that a restriction for swapping between up and down mode is that the clock must be high on the first device in ripple-clocking mode. Your second device is connected more like a first device. So I see the possibility of things going wrong there.

Comment: I tried to connect it like in datasheet without success (viz reply on first anwer). I dont quite get the second part, how can i ensure that clock will be high?